# how to delete second object in canvas using fabric js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js to make some drawings and text but i wonder how to select first object when second image got overlay on it in canvas .

in this example i want to select the circle which was overlap by a triangle

i used send to sendBackwards function

**Code**

```
var selected_object = canvas.getActiveObject();
canvas.sendBackwards(selected_object);`
```

other than that is there any way to achieve

**[My Plunker Code](https://embed.plnkr.co/cmdHqfQ1vgmYhai7z6c3/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
canvas.perPixelTargetFind = true;
```

This will allow you to select targets just where they are not transparent.

Comment: thank you ..This made my day ... great to see answer from official contributor of fabricjs